# Unique User id for Google Home actions is not unique

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

This gives `undefined` when requested from device:

```
originalRequest.data.device.uniqueDeviceId
```

`originalRequest.data.user.userId` gives the user id same as `getUser().userId`, which is not unique. This id changes every time for the user.

Which is the unique Id for a user to identify that the user is unique?

Answer (score 6):

The `uniqueDeviceId` was never documented by Google and was removed since it could be used to reveal information without the user's permission.

The `userId` as you've defined it, either through `getUser()` or through the JSON, is the correct way to uniquely identify a user.

In general, it **will** be consistent between calls, however, [there are a number of cases where it will change](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info). Most notably:

- If the user is on a speaker, but does not match any registered voice profile for that device (or there is no registered voice profile on the device). In these cases, the user is "anonymous" and has to be treated that way by the system for their ID.
- If the user resets the identifier for the Action (in the same way they might delete a web cookie).
- If the user resets their account on a device.
- If the user doesn't use your Action for 30 days.

**Update**

The anonymous userId [has been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) and will be removed in May 2019. If you need a userId for the user, you can either use [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/) or generate it yourself and [store it in the user storage object](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data). Neither of these have the same limitations outlined above.